# How to add ToolBar button to Tool Bar in my Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using XCode
I have added a Toolbar to my Navigation Controller. And I want to add Bar Buttons to that toolBar.
In my storyboard, I try control drag 'Bar Button Item' to the tool bar, but that does not work, nothing gets added.

So can 'Bar Button Item' to the tool bar?

Thank you.

Update:

I add my own UINavigationController, bind the toolbar from storyboard to my class as 'mytoolbar'. 
And did the answer code in swift, 
But when I run it on simulator, I don't see any tool bar item.

```
class AppNavigationController: UINavigationController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mytoolbar: UIToolbar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        var rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("method"))
        var items = [AnyObject]()

        items.append(rightButton)
        mytoolbar.items = items

    }

    func method() {
        println("Something cool here")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift:

```
 let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "touchPickImage")

 let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "deleteImage")

 toolBar.setItems([item], animated: true)
```

you can get reference for tool bar either from view controller or you drag it and then add.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to go with a programmatic solution here:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title 1"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(buttonClick1:)];
UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title 1"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(buttonClick2:)];
NSMutableArray *myButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, button2, nil];
toolBar.items = myButtonArray;
```

Comment: I created my Navigator Controller by " drag out a Navigation Controller to add iOS’s built-in navigation logic to the project. This will create two view controllers on the storyboard – the navigation controller itself and a table view controller inside that will be the initial view for the application." So where should I put the code above? How do I get my reference to toolbar? I don't have a 'custom class' for my Navigator Controller.

Comment: You should be able to add this code to your View Controller instead - simply add it in the `viewDidLoad` method, and change the `toolBar.items` to `self.navigationcontroller.navigationitem.rightbarbuttonitem` or `self.navigationcontroller.navigationitem.leftbarbuttonitem` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your bar button items, then using:

self.setToolbarItems([UIBarButtonItem], animated: false)